# How to pass value of a binding variable to a method in the template on button clicked

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am learing how to make binding between the parent and the child using @Input, @Output and EventEmitter decorators.
in the html section posted below

```
<h1 appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}</h1>

currentItem has value equal to "TV". and i pass this value to the binding variable item.
```

i added console.log in ngOnInit that prints the value of item to make sure that the binding from the parent to the child is working as suppose to be.

in

```
<button (click) = addNewItem(item.value)></button>
```

in this button tag i am trying to pass the value of the binding variable item to the method addNewItem() as a parameter.
For the method addNewItem() it exists in the component and it should be invoked with the right parameter which is the value of the binding variable item

when i compile the App i revceive the error posted below.
please let me know how to pass the value of the binding variable to a method on button clicked

**error**

```
TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

2 <button (click) = addNewItem(item.value)></button>
                               ~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'InputOutputBindings';
  currentItem = 'TV';

  @Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(val : string) {
    this.newItemValue.emit(val);
    console.log("add new item");
  }
}
```

**item-details.directive.ts**:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appItemDetails]'
})
export class ItemDetailsDirective {

  @Input() item : string = "";

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit->:" + this.item)
  }

}
```

**app.coponent.html**:

```
<h1 appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}</h1>
<button (click) = addNewItem(item.value)></button>
```

Comment: is addNewItem is supposed to be addNewItem(currentItem)

Comment: @Pradeep yes i want to do that when the buttonis clicked...that's why i want to know how to access item from the template

Comment: why do you want to do item.value, you can do currentItem in which the binding value is present

Comment: @Pradeep because i want to learn how to do it please

Comment: Since you're already binding `currentItem` to `item`, can't you just use : `<button (click) = addNewItem(currentItem)></button>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add exportAs like below:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appItemDetails]'
  exportAs: 'customdirective',
})
export class ItemDetailsDirective {
....
}
```

and in your html, you can add a reference to directive and get the binded value:

```
<h1 #test="customdirective" appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}</h1>
<button (click) = addNewItem(test.item)></button>
```